# Firefox extension DOM manipulation using content script

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to make changes on the current web page's dom

```
tabs.activeTab.attach({  
                contentScript:
window.content.document.body.length); // is showing undefined
```

so I am not able to iterate over all the dom elements and make changes to them. 
And when I directly tried to write the tag I got a security exception

Please suggest me a way to access window object.

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't working for me either, but the `contentScript` property only takes a String or Array so you'll need to do something like this:

```
var tabs = require('tabs');
tabs.activeTab.attach({
  contentScript: 'console.log(window.content.document.body.toString());'
});
```

You should be able to modify the DOM from there but unless you include jQuery it'll be a bit harder using `document.querySelectorAll` and then working with raw DOM Element nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. there is security exception if i try do modify the dom